# How to use curl call a php to get file url first and then download?

Tags: linux, curl, cron

On my webserver, the PHP code can get the latest file list.

On another Linux server, I want to use **CRON** and **cURL** to call this PHP code to get the file list first, and then download the file.

```
curl http://www.website.com/index.php
```

This code works and its results are string URL. (eg: http://www.website.com/files/new.zip )

However, I don't know how to post this string to curl for downloading this files. What I am tring to do is like this:

```
curl -O (curl http://www.website.com/index.php )
```

How can I make this work? Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that I am not running curl in PHP. I have to run curl in a linux server. Later on, I will use CRON to run the curl automatically every 1 minute.

Comment: It deserves to try. But I don't have the root account for the linux server. What should install in the linux server? I probably can ask the administration staff to help me install.

Comment: I removed PHP tag as this has nothing to do with PHP

Answer (score 2):

You was almost there:

```
curl $(curl "http://www.website.com/index.php")
```

If you want to hide progress:

```
curl $(curl -s "http://www.website.com/index.php")
```

---

Looks like OP had line breaks/caret returns in outputed URL so `http://....` became `.ttp://....`

Comment: @YuGuo can you show me the full command you used? It works flawlessly for me (bash 4.4.12)

Comment: Sure. In the PHP code, I echo the link to the file, looks like this: echo (http://website/files/new.zip). Then, I am in the linux server trying to use your code. curl $(curl "http://www.website.com/index.php")

Comment: @YuGuo can you please show me what `curl "website.com/index.php"` returns? you propably need  to add http:// and maybe www.

Comment: Can I send you private message? So I can send the link to you.

Comment: curl "http://website/index.php" returns an url. I can copy this url and paste on a browser, then the file can be downloaded.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  @Peter

Comment: By the way, what does dollar sign mean?

Comment: @YuGuo $ means accessing variable. https://askubuntu.com/questions/833833/what-does-command-do/833848